# How to connect to mongo server using Studio 3t behind proxy?

Tags: mongodb, proxy, studio3t

Using [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com/) (free), how could I connect to a remote server if my (computer) Studio 3T is behind a proxy.

The proxy uses authentication, but I could use [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) for handling the authentication for me.

Possible scenarios:

1. `Studio 3T <---> Proxy <---> Remote MongoDB` *`(Internet)`*
2. `Studio 3T <---> Cntlm <---> Proxy <---> Remote MongoDB` *`(Internet)`*

Env: Ubuntu 18.04

PS: I've read [Configure MongoDB Ops Manager to Use an HTTP Proxy for Outgoing Traffic](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/use-with-http-proxy/), but it would require additional packages/tools installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're currently performing the finishing touches on proxy support in Studio 3T which will be available in an upcoming release.

Regarding versions, we have a non-commercial license for non-commercial use, while use of Studio 3T in a corporate setting requires a commercial license. We highly encourage you to check out all the additional advantages and productivity-boosting features of our Core, Pro, and Enterprise editions: http://studio3t.com/compare/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, now future readers may find the feature documentation here: https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/connect-to-mongodb/#proxy-settings